# developed insect bloodsuckers meaning

Tags: word-meaning

> Mosquitoes are the most highly developed insect bloodsuckers.
>
> What does highly developed mean in this sentence?
>
> I can't figure out whether it means "most intelligent or
>   grow fast most"

Comment: Most evolved, or something like that.

Comment: "highly developed ... bloodsuckers" means they have evolved with advanced techniques or organs for sucking blood.

Answer (score 2):

> highly developed

can mean either *very intelligent* or *very skilled* depending on context.

> most highly developed insect bloodsuckers

means that over a period of evolution, mosquitoes have mastered the techniques necessary to be able to suck blood from other animals.

This may be due to its light weight, flying agility, attraction to CO2 (and thus live animals), long probe for extracting blood, or natural anticoagulate which it uses to ensure that blood does not clot while being sucked.

Comment: My fingers do the same thing after a day on the internet.